# Implement d3 Click-to-zoom

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js

I'm new to web stuff but even I know this is a stupid question... I still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong though. The code on the site here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590 seems as if you could copy and paste it into an html document and merely modify the link to the us.json so that it points to the full file path. However, the code merely pulls up a blank page. 
The inspection of the page source code on the demo ( http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/2206590/ )is the exact same as the code provided on the main page. What am I missing to implement this??
Thanks!!!

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.background {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

#states {
  fill: #aaa;
}

#states .active {
  fill: orange;
}

#state-borders {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  pointer-events: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    centered;

var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
    .scale(1070)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "background")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("click", clicked);

var g = svg.append("g");

d3.json("/mbostock/raw/4090846/us.json", function(error, us) {
  if (error) throw error;

  g.append("g")
      .attr("id", "states")
    .selectAll("path")
      .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
      .on("click", clicked);

  g.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
      .attr("id", "state-borders")
      .attr("d", path);
});

function clicked(d) {
  var x, y, k;

  if (d && centered !== d) {
    var centroid = path.centroid(d);
    x = centroid[0];
    y = centroid[1];
    k = 4;
    centered = d;
  } else {
    x = width / 2;
    y = height / 2;
    k = 1;
    centered = null;
  }

  g.selectAll("path")
      .classed("active", centered && function(d) { return d === centered; });

  g.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")scale(" + k + ")translate(" + -x + "," + -y + ")")
      .style("stroke-width", 1.5 / k + "px");
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the `us.json` file and put it in the same directory as your `index.html`. Then change the path to the `us.json` file:

`d3.json("us.json", function(error, us) {`

This worked for me. If you are using Chrome and accessing the `index.html` file on your local computer, not from a remote webserver, you will need to run a local webserver for this to work. If you just try to open the `index.html` file in Chrome, it won't display properly due to Chrome's local file restrictions. It needs to be accessed through a webserver.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted. If you choose to down-vote something, an explanation would be nice.

Comment: Ah it must be the Chrome file restrictions that are causing me problems.  I hadn't considered that, thanks! I put an upvote in for you but my rep's still below 15. I'll try it again once I get my rep up

Comment: No problem. Amazing that someone would downvote an answer that actually helps somebody. I upvoted your question back to zero. Thanks for accepting the answer!